# tsung-recorder unable to capture browser traffic

Tags: tsung, tsung-recorder

All I see in the captured XML file is an ending session tag. I've set manual proxy to point to Tsung port(9000) and launched URL in private browser mode to avoid cache.

```
ram@saket:~$ tsung-recorder -L 9000 -P 8000 start
Starting Tsung recorder on port 9000
ram@saket:~$ "Record file: /home/ram/.tsung/tsung_recorder20130328-1645.xml"
ram@saket:~$ tsung-recorder stop
[OK]
ram@saket:~$ cat /home/ram/.tsung/tsung_recorder20130328-1645.xml
</session>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you a proxy between your host and where you want to go ? If you set -P for the parent proxy you have to set -u too or remove -P if you do not have a parent proxy.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that I did not notice my browser was bypassing proxy for local addresses.